# Use current filename ("{}") multiple times in "find -exec"?

Tags: shell, find

Many sources say that every instance of {} will be replaced with the filename found through find, but when I try to run the following, I only get one text file and its name is ".txt"

```
find /directory -name "*pattern*" -exec cut -f8 {} > {}.txt \;
```

The goal was to create a text file with only the eighth column from each file found, and each text file will be named after its parent file. Something about that second set of {} is not replacing with the filename of each found file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try:

```
find /directory -name "*pattern*" -exec sh -c 'cut -f8 {} > {}.txt' \;
```

But be aware that some versions of find require `{}` to be a distinct argument, and will not expand `{}` to a filename otherwise.  You can work around that with:

```
find /directory -name "*pattern*" -exec sh -c 'cut -f8 $0 > $0.txt' {} \;
```

(this alternate command will put the output file in the subdirectory which contains the matched file.  If desired, you could avoid that by redirecting to `${0#*/}`

The issue is that `find` is not doing the redirection, the shell is.  Your command is exactly equivalent to:

```
# Sample of INCORRECT code
find /directory -name "*pattern*" -exec cut -f8 {} \; > {}.txt
```

Note the following from the standard:

*If more than one argument containing only the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.*

If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}" , but not just the two characters "{}" , it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.

Comment: I see, your fix did the trick. Thanks!

I was wondering if the > was being misinterpreted

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to others, but the `sh` part of the command is launching a "child shell" which lets you do more "shell-y" stuff like re-directs etc. See this nice post for more details. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find/389706#389706?newreg=51a16c7c5d574bf4a4d28afa56c0fbb1

Answer (score 18):

To deal with the caveats that William Pursell mentioned in his answer, use the following:

```
find /directory -name "*pattern*" -exec sh -c 'cut -f8 "$1" > "$1.txt"' x {} \;
```

When you use `sh -c`, it gets the positional parameters from arguments following the string to execute. The extra `x` fills in `$0`, and the substituted filename will become `$1`.

The double quotes allow this to work properly with filenames containing spaces and other special characters.

Comment: Any reason not to use $0: `sh -c '...$0...' {}`?

Comment: Mostly it just feels "wrong" -- $0 is supposed to be the name of shell, not a parameter. I don't know how portable it is to use it there.

Comment: For some reason I found THIS solution the most elegant. And worked great.. For files with spaces/etc in their names, you may wish to put double quotes around the $1..

Comment: @TurgutKalfaoglu I do have double quotes around it, and even mentioned it in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /directory -name "*pattern*" | xargs awk '{z=FILENAME".txt";print $8>z}'
```