# gzip contents found by recursive find without deleting originals?

Tags: bash, find

I want to gzip all of my CSS files recursively. But my command is not working properly.

I'm using `find` with the `-exec` option

```
$ find . -name "*.css" -exec gzip -c "{}" > "{}.gz" \;
```

When using `-exec echo` (or just leave the `-exec` part) it's clearly finding my `plugin[1,2].min.css` together with `index.css` but when using `-exec gzip` it's just ignoring any files, unless `index.css`.

The file size of `index.css.gz` is the same as when running gzip manually for `index.css`.

I've no idea whats going on. Any ideas?

---

```
$ tree
.
├── css
│   ├── custom
│   │   └── index.css
│   └── vendor
│       ├── plugin1
│       │   └── plugin1.min.css
│       └── plugin2
│           └── plugin2.min.css
 # ...

$ find . -name "*.css" -exec gzip -c "{}" > "{}.gz" \;
$ tree
.
├── css
│   ├── custom
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   └── index.css.gz
│   └── vendor
│       ├── plugin1
│       │   └── plugin1.min.css
│       └── plugin2
│           └── plugin2.min.css
```

Comment: Currently `> "{}.gz"` is captured by the shell and not find; also, you can't do redirection in a `find -exec` command anyway. Use `bash -c "blah"` as the `-exec` command.

Comment: By the way, beware of quoting of paths. To be safe, you should pass the path as an argument to `bash -c`: `find . -name '*.css' -exec bash -c 'gzip -c "$1" > "$1".gz' -- {} \;`.

Comment: What does the double dash at the end do? Also: you could post this as an answer!

Comment: `man bash`: If  the  `-c`  option  is  present,  then  commands  are  read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, they are assigned to  the  positional parameters, starting with `$0`. But you want to assign to `$1`.

Comment: I'll post it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Post it as answer, but add `-type f` ;)

Comment: *sigh*. I'm **absolutely positive** that this is a duplicate, but finding the original question is being a bit elusive.

Comment: Hmm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030563/redirecting-stdout-with-find-exec-and-without-creating-new-shell is somewhat on-point; likewise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965400/use-current-filename-multiple-times-in-find-exec

Answer (score 2):

`gzip foo.txt bar.txt` creates `foo.txt.gz` and `bar.txt.gz`, with no need for extra output redirections.

So, consider

```
find . -type f -name '*.css' -exec gzip {} +
```

as a simpler way to approach this task.

**Edit**

So, I can't read questions accurately: OP needs to keep the source .css files around. Fair enough.

To flog the "simpler `find` command" approach, I might create a separate utility script that would more cleanly handle spaces and other special characters in directory and file names. Call it `do_the_gzip` (make it executable, etc.):

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ $# -ge 1 ]; do
  gzip -c "$1" > "$1".gz
  shift
done
```

**Edit 2**

Charles Duffy has a nice suggestion in the comments, teaching me something new: shell `for` loops iterate over `"$@"` implicitly, so the script can be simpler:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f; do gzip -c "$f" > "$f".gz; done
```

*...end of Edit 2.*

Then the find command still looks similar:

```
find . -type f -name '*.css' -exec do_the_gzip {} +
```

and where there are directories and/or files with white space, quotes, and shell globbing characters, it can work cleanly.

Sorry for the careless first reading of the question.

Comment: Apparently what OP wants here is to create the gzipped files AND retain the original files.

Comment: What @4ae1e1 said is correct.

Comment: Ah - my mistake. Thanks for the correction, and see the edit above.

Comment: No need for the `while` / `shift` fun: a `for` loop will do what you want automatically. `for f; do gzip -c "$f" >"$f.gz"; done` -- the default thing for a `for` loop to iterate over is `"$@"`, and that frees you from needing to check `$#` also.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy! A bit of learning for me today...

Comment: No need to apologize. I still prefer @4ae1e1's answer since it's simpler tho. Thanks for your effort tho.