# 'find' all .log files under a directory, copy them to another directory named after their parent directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Random e.g.:

```
/stack-exchange/
|
|-- stack-overflow/
|   |-- questions/
|   |-- people/
|   |-- site.log
|-- super-user/
|   |-- questions/
|   |-- people/
|   |-- answers.log
|-- ask-ubuntu/
|   |-- questions/
|   |-- people/
|   |-- linux.log
|-- logs/
```

This is the command I'd use to `find` all log files in a given directory:

```
find /stack-exchange/ -type f -name "*.log"
```

Now, going by the example, I'd like to copy all 3 log files (site.log, answers.log & linux.log) to `/stack-exchange/logs` directory and have them named after their parent directory, like so:

```
/stack-exchange/
|
|-- [...]
|
|-- logs/
|   |-- stack-overflow.log
|   |-- super-user.log
|   |-- ask-ubuntu.log
```

How do I do that? I've tried this:

```
find /stack-exchange/ -type f -iname "*.log" -exec cp "{}" "../logs/$(basename "$(dirname "{}")").log" \;
```

I think I am close, but it doesn't work. All it does is create a `..log` file. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can't use `{}` multiple times like that. You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965400/use-current-filename-multiple-times-in-find-exec)

Comment: @rdupz Thank you! (Posted answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965441/1071413) to the question [**Use current filename ("{}") multiple times in "find -exec"?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965400/use-current-filename-multiple-times-in-find-exec), this works:*

```
find /stack-exchange/ -type f -iname "*.log" -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "./logs/$(basename "$(dirname "$0")").log"' {} \;
```

---

<sup>Thank you @rdupz ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959708/find-all-log-files-under-a-directory-copy-them-to-another-directory-named-af#comment69129053_40959708)), for pointing me in the right direction.</sup>