# How do I json-format and override multiple files?

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, command-line

I have several unformatted json files I would like to "prettify" so they're more human readable. The way I usually do it for a single file is:

```
python -m json.tool < infile > outfile
```

But for several files I haven't found a way to process them and override the same file with the new "pretty" json.

The closest I got was:

```
find ./ -type f -exec python -m json.tool {} \;
```

But it prints everything to standard output, which is fine but not optimal depending on how many files you're looking at. Is there any way to make the above command override the files with the prettified json?

Files are called: message1.json, message2.json and so on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: See at https://stackoverflow.com/q/12965400/4886927 (replace the "cut" command by your pyhton one)

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: I'm not sure I would call it an exact dupe, I'm not sure if OP wants his filename extension altered. Would be useful if they provide more information

Comment: @israelord: Can you give us some actual file name and file contents? Also would you like the extension to  be changed from original file to the new JSON? Or have the same name

Comment: @Inian extension should be kept as json, just override the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'python -m json.tool $0 > $0.pretty' {} \;
```

see at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965441/4886927 for detailed explanation

In this way the original file is overwritten with new one:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'python -m json.tool < $0 > /tmp/pretty.json && mv  /tmp/pretty.json $0' \;
```

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the same extension?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the already accepted answer, but it uses `sponge` (on debian, this is part of the `moreutils` package) to avoid creating an intermediate file in `/tmp`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec sh -c 'python3 -m json.tool < $0 | sponge $0' {} \;
```