# How to get two outputs from a bash find exec command

Tags: linux, bash, find, exec

I host a photo gallery. There is a command you run to automatically add content. It looks like this;

```
php artisan lychee:sync /path/to/import --album_id="album ID"
```

This command needs two variables;

1. path to import
2. Album ID

I’m running Find against a directory to return any sub directories added within the last 5 days;

```
find /mnt/Pictures -mtime -5 -mindepth 1
/mnt/Pictures/Paris Trip
/mnt/Pictures/Spain
/mnt/Pictures/America
```

Now, I can invoke the script to add this content using the -exec function in Find, but the value of {} is the path to import. I need both the path to import AND the name of the directory; such as

```
php artisan lychee:sync /mnt/Pictures/Spain --album_id="Spain"
```

This is where I am so far;

```
find /mnt/Pictures -mtime -5 -mindepth 1 -exec php artisan lychee:sync {} \;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965400/use-current-filename-multiple-times-in-find-exec) answer your question?  Using that method you can e.g. use `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` against the second  `{}` ...

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `sh` call to the mix:

```
find /mnt/Pictures -mtime -5 -mindepth 1 -exec \
    sh -c 'php artisan lychee:sync "$1" --album_id="$(basename "$1")"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use a bash loop as so:

```
find /mnt/Pictures -mtime -5 -mindepth 1 -print0 | \
   while IFS= read -r -d '' pth; do  \
      php artisan lychee:sync "${pth}" --albumId="${pth##*/}"; \
   done;
```

Comment: oops.  Thanks fixed.